# Prometheus JSON file or the maximum amount of data that can be retrieved through this API

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I'm currently working on extracting data using the Prometheus API query in JSON format.

However, I'm unsure if there's a limit to the size of the JSON file or the maximum amount of data that can be retrieved through this API.

I've been searching for reference documentation, but haven't found anything yet.

If any of you have experience with this and could share your insights or recommendations, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here's an example of the API endpoint : https://k8s02-workspace-abcd.eastus.prometheus.monitor.azure.com/api/v1/query?query=extractdata

Thank you in advance for your help!

JSON File Size Limit

Comment: Consider asking this question at Prometheus' repo [issues](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues).